# How to use the same shortcode with different attribute values on same page

Tags: shortcode

I need quick help in shortcode attributes

This is my code

```
 function display($atts){

    ob_start();
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "isi_ads_details";

    $attts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '2',
    ), $atts, 'Adds' );

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename."";  
    $ad_display = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

    foreach($ad_display as $display){

        if($attts['id'] == $display['id']){
          echo '<img src="'.$display['upload_image'].'" alt="Image" />';    
        }

    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('Adds', 'display');
```

What i need is, i want to display both shortcode result on same page. But it is displaying only one result that is **id="2"**

```
[Adds id="2"]
[Adds id="3"]
```

Comment: Are you 100% positive that there is an element that matches `( "3" == $display['id'] )` in the `$ad_display` array?

Comment: Yes, in my database there is ID for 2, 3 etc. Please see the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/9GdZ8tjt

Comment: You spelled $attts with 3 t's instead of 2.

Comment: That's also i tried. But no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code when it comes to attributes (except maybe that having `$attts` and `$atts` makes the code much harder to read than it needs to be).

I reduced your code to this test case:

```
function display($atts){
    ob_start();

    $attts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '2',
    ), $atts, 'Adds' );

    echo $attts['id'];

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'Adds', 'display' );
```

When I added the shortcode to a page the correct id attributes were echoed.

This means that the problem must exist in your data. Either `$display['id']` or `$display['upload_image']` are not what you expect them to be or `$ad_display` isn't.

Without being able to see your actual data, it's impossible to be more precise than that. So to answer your question "How to use the same shortcode with different attribute values on same page", the answer is that you can do it and your code is written correctly to do it. Your issue is specific to your data.

Some additional pointers unrelated to the question:

- `display()` is far too generic a name for a function. Prefix it or namespace it with something specific to your project to avoid conflicts.
- It's "ads", not "adds".
- Why not just query the specific ID you're looking for instead of querying *all* the data for every shortcode and then looping through it to find a match?

Comment: No problem. What did the actual problem turn out to be?

Comment: Actually what i did is, i include a file only once. After seeing your code i replace the include once to include. Thank you!